# MySQL query won't return any rows when adding OFFSET

Tags: mysql, sql, offset

Trying to add offset to a mysqli query, but it won't return any rows:

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published='1' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published='1' ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 20
```

Comment: Yep, you can't just make up syntax

Comment: OFFSET is an addition to LIMIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this syntax instead as OFFSET needs LIMIT keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 20;
```

This means that it will return the limit of fetched rows 40 only and skipping the first 20 rows.

You can check this link https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp that can help you.